# Iframe Resizer not resizing?

Tags: javascript, iframe, iframe-resizer

I'm using David J Bradshaw's iframe resizer but I can't get it to resize at all.

- iframeSizer.min.js included in my container page
- This code in the head of my container page: `&lt;script> $('iframe').iFrameResize( [{log:true}]&nbsp;); &lt;/script>`
- iframeSizer.contentWindow.min.js included in my framed page
- the iframe set to width="100" and scrolling="no"

Here is the [test page](http://4cforchildren.org/providers/workshops-courses/test-resizer-page.aspx).

Comment: Try wrapping your `$('iframe').iFrameResize( [{log:true}] ); ` in a `$(document).ready(function() { ... }`

Comment: will you not also need to include the JQuery library in the container page in addition to the js include ?

Comment: The call to iFrameResize should be passed an object, not an object array!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue might be that the JavaScript that should to the work isn't loaded when you call `$('iframe').iFrameResize({log:true});`. So in order to make it work add a `$(document).ready` statement:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('iframe').iFrameResize({log:true});
});
```

Comment: THANK YOU. That was it! I'll accept this as the answer as soon as it lets me...I really appreciate you explaining why it needed the `$(document).ready` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code in a `document.ready`. When the JavaScript is called the HTML is not loaded therefore it is undefined or null.

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('iframe').iFrameResize({log:true}); 
    });
</script>
```